# unable to see PROGRESS STATUS in type STORY

Tags: scrum, jira-agile

Project Type: scrum type
request is of type STORY, I'm unable to see PROGRESS STATUS in the request. 
Default Story Screen is also set, but screen also I'm unable to see PROGRESS STATUS as field.
Here's a twist, if i create another story in the same project, i can see PROGRESS STATUS'.
Also, request contains EPIC LINK too!!!!

As a admin, i can see option to add the required field in the story request.
If I'll add field, it will affect the current screen assigned to the project?

What could be the issue that caused field not associated while creating?

---

Edit1:

These are the option i'm able to see:
[image]

This is what i expect to see (If i'll create a new  Story Type, i can see these options (Start Progress))
[image]

View Workflow(same for above 2 instance)
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that PROGRESS STATUS is a custom field.

On the story where you were unable to see PROGRESS STATUS, did it have a value set? You can see from the "Where is my field?" screen the last item mentions that only when PROGRESS STATUS has a value will it be shown. That is one possible problem.

The "Where is my field?" screen is also indicating that the screen scheme for the current project does not include your custom field. If you click on the "Story Screen Scheme" link on "Where is my field?" you should be able to add the missing field. This will make the PROGRESS STATUS field visible for *every* project that uses the "Story Screen Scheme".

The final thing to check is the custom field configuration. JIRA is careful with custom fields, it does not make them visible in every project by default. You need to enable them for each project you want them to be visible in.

Comment: since i'm new to jira... unable to see "start progress" option in the story request... can u judge y it is so?

Comment: Sorry Annadate, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I've updated the question. check Edit1.

Comment: On the same screen, can you see the link that says 'View Workflow'? It is in the middle of the screen, in brackets and just under the buttons. Click on 'View Workflow' and it will show you the workflow you are currently using. If there are no valid transitions from where you are to 'Start Progress' then this button would not appear.

Comment: yes, i've check'd with 'View Workflow', Workflow is USER STORIES 1.1, and Start Progress is also present for the type story where "Start Progress" option in enable n not enabled. (view workflow screenshot added)

Comment: OK, there are three things that need to be true for you to see 'Start Progress': 1. Your story needs to currently be in the state 'Open'. 2. You need to satisfy all the conditions on the transition from 'Open' to 'In Progress' (you can view the conditions in the workflow view) 3. You need to have permission on this project to do transitions.

Comment: 1. Story is in open state
2.conditions to satisfy? workflow view does not contain any condition for view.
3. I'm JIRA-ADMIN and the project Admin cannot view the transition option. Person who created the story has the 'Transition Issues' permission

Barnaby, i can feel, this may be due to some patch/updation going on in jira while the story was created. this can be ?

Comment: In the edit workflow view, click on one of the lines (the transitions). A box pops up that shows the details of the transition. In the box are links for: properties, triggers, conditions, validators and post functions. If you click on conditions then you see the conditions necessary for the transition to be allowed. Might be worth checking the validators as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84143/discussion-between-annadate-piyush-and-barnaby-golden).

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Tried to move the story into another project (better with scrum->kanban or vice-versa) and again to your original project.
You need to remember the other fields such as component link if any !!!